# How to use stitches and tailwind together in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, stitches

Is there a way to combine the power of both stitches (https://stitches.dev/) and tailwind https://tailwindcss.com/ in a Next.js project? How to use them together?

Comment: I tried to map tailwind.config.cjs to the values in createTheme but failed. I use them over top of each other and duplicating settings as a makeshift solution.  Hopefully someone can show us the way!

Comment: You can use [CVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74199590/how-to-use-stitches-and-tailwind-together-in-next-js) instead. It kind of stitches for tailwind.